# Android get mobile phones screensize inside View

Tags: android

I am trying to draw x and y axis line, but I can't get the user's phone size. How is this done inside a view? I have tried this:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
int width = dm.widthPixels;
int height = dm.heightPixels;
```

The entire Android class code is the following:
http://pastebin.com/J02irHd8

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In an Activity or Context run the following code:

```
getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels
```

If you are in a View then try

```
getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels
```